# How to validate date field for a model (Yii2)

Tags: validation, yii2

Could anybody give me a nice example of validation a date field?

I have the following `rules` validation method:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['rewards_date_from', 'rewards_date_to'], 'date', 'dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d'], 

...
```

`'rewards_date_from', 'rewards_date_to'` - both fields have date type with format `Y-m-d`.

But this rules are wrong. Yii throws me the following exception:

> Setting unknown property: yii\validators\DateValidator::dateFormat

Ok, I'm trying to validate it like:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['rewards_date_from', 'rewards_date_to'], 'date'], 

...
```

And I have the model errors:
[image]

The messages mean: "Wrong format of Rewards date from" and the same for `rewards_date_to` field.

My input data is:

[image]

and the same for `rewards_date_from` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation says, [Class yii\validators\DateValidator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-datevalidator#$format-detail), you must use `format` property to validate date field.

Try this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       [['rewards_date_from', 'rewards_date_to'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d'],
...
```